# Printing NUL in log file while Converting Char Arrays to String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am reading response from TCP call and I have to read chars only. Reading each char takes too much time so I am creating array with maximum number the response might be. Problem in this approach that response length is less and array size is big. While converting that into String its also using those blank chars which were not used while reading response because of that its writing "NUL" into log file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestArrayToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        char[] chars = new char[5];
        chars[0] = 'K';
        chars[1] = 'S';
        chars[2] = 'H';
        String s = new String(chars);
        System.out.println(s);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("C://projects//test//test.log"));
        fw.write(s);
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Is there any possibility to remove that NUL while writing.

Comment: You should know the number of characters in the byte array that are valid. You can use the ``String​(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)`` constructor to convert to a string.

Comment: Why do you have to read char's only? You could use a BufferedReader and use readLine(), if the TCP data includes a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are objects. When they are initialized (instantiated), each element of the array is initialized to their default values. For example, primitive numeric values are initialized to the number 0. Objects are initialized by default to NULL. Character primitives or `char` are initialized to Unicode value 0 (\U0000) which happens to be the null character.

Your code is initializing an array of five chars. Only the first three elements are set with new character values. The last two still contain default values.

To fix this, you either need to create a smaller array, or only convert to String characters containing not null values. An easy way to do this is by trimming. Something like this should work:

```
char[] chars = new char[5];
...
String s = String.valueOf(chars).trim();
```

**UPDATE**

Another added benefit to this solution is avoiding creating a new `String` for repeated values.

```
String s = new String(chars); // BAD
String s = String.valueOf(chars); // Preferred
```

The preferred answer only creates a new String if the value represented by the array of characters is not present in the String pool. If it is, it uses the already existing String. The `String` copy constructor creates a duplicate String (it disregards the String pool).